# In jenkins-kubernetes-plugin, how to generate labels in Pod template that are based on a pattern

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes-ingress, jenkins-kubernetes

****Set-Up****

I am using [jenkins-kubernetes-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) to run our QE jobs. The QE jobs are executed over multiple PODs and each POD has a static set of labels like testing chrome

**Issue:**

In these QE jobs, there is one port say 7900 that I want to expose through Kubernetes Ingress Controller.

The issue is we have multiple PODs running from the same Pod Template and they all have the same set of labels. For Ingress Controller to work, I want these PODs to have some labels that come from a pattern.

Like POD1 has a label chrome-1 and POD2 has a label called  chrome-2 and so on...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible directly, but you could use groovy in the pipeline to customize it, ie. add the build id as a label